# PHP7.3-FPM with Apache: Unknown script request execution timed out

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, timeout, php7, mpm-event

I configured Apache 2.4 MPM Event with PHP7.3-FPM on a pretty busy web server as follows:

```
Timeout 90

<Proxy "unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">
    ProxySet disablereuse=on timeout=90
</Proxy>

<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
        SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
</FilesMatch>
```

The PHP config in /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini is set to

```
max_execution_time=60
```

The PHP-FPM is configured in /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf to

```
request_terminate_timeout=90
```

The read timeouts are configured in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/reqtimeout.conf like this:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-120,minrate=50
RequestReadTimeout body=60-120,minrate=50
```

In FPM log now I can see every minute 1-2 workers for unknown requests which are killed after 90+ seconds.

```
[16-May-2019 09:25:32] WARNING: [pool www] child 105567, script '' (request: " ") execution timed out (113.002653 sec), terminating
[16-May-2019 09:25:32] WARNING: [pool www] child 105567 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 4050.136381 seconds from start
[16-May-2019 09:25:32] NOTICE: [pool www] child 110414 started
```

If I don't set `request_terminate_timeout` to kill these workers they stay longer (~5 minutes) in state "Reading headers" and block the PHP-FPM pool.

The threads in Apache MPM seem not to get blocked anyway. Nothing is hitting the max workers values.

How can I see which script/request these PHP workers belong to? Why these scripts are running even after `max_execution_time` of 60 seconds has expired? How can I avoid blocking the PHP pool by such requests?

I suspect there could be sometimes incomplete HTTPS requests which are starting the PHP worker somehow. Is there a way to avoid starting a PHP worker for these?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, with all updated Apache and PHP still the same stuff.

Comment: I found a solution, at least to my very similar problem: I removed `enablereuse=on` from the `<Proxy>` directive in my Apache conf. Read the last response from here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69890

Comment: My proxy config is already with disablereuse=on. With enablereuse=on there has been some serious issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @constantin-galbenu mentions in [their comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/967523/php7-3-fpm-with-apache-unknown-script-request-execution-timed-out#comment1282615_967523), the Apache `<Proxy>` directive's `enablereuse=on` does not play well with PHP-FPM's prefork multi-processing model as described in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69890

> [2019-05-02 10:03 UTC] mp at webfactory dot de
>
> For the record, the Apache manual at
> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#examples
> says:
>
> > Enable connection reuse to a FCGI backend like PHP-FPM
> >
> > Please keep in mind that PHP-FPM (at the time of writing, February
> > 2018) uses a prefork model, namely each of its worker processes can
> > handle one connection at the time. By default mod_proxy (configured
> > with enablereuse=on) allows a connection pool of ThreadsPerChild
> > connections to the backend for each httpd process when using a
> > threaded mpm (like worker or event), so the following use cases should
> > be taken into account:
> >
> > Under HTTP/1.1 load it will likely cause the creation of up to
> > MaxRequestWorkers connections to the FCGI backend.
> >
> > Under HTTP/2 load, due to how mod_http2 is implemented, there are
> > additional h2 worker threads that may force the creation of other
> > backend connections. The overall count of connections in the pools may
> > raise to more than MaxRequestWorkers.
> >
> > The maximum number of PHP-FPM worker processes needs to be configured
> > wisely, since there is the chance that they will all end up "busy"
> > handling idle persistent connections, without any room for new ones to
> > be established, and the end user experience will be a pile of HTTP
> > request timeouts.
>
> My interpretation of this is that with enablereuse=on, every Apache
> MPM worker process/thread can have an open connection to PHP-FPM. In
> the PHP-FPM status page, those will show up as "Reading headers..."
> (or similar). These processes seem to be active (waiting) for PHP-FPM
> and so they are not terminated.

My own issue was with webservers using Apache's [event](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html) Multi-Processing Module (MPM) passing PHP execution to PHP-FPM using the example configuration from Apache's [mod_proxy_fcgi documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html):

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    # Note: The only part that varies is /path/to/app.sock
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/path/to/app.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>

# Define a matching worker.
# The part that is matched to the SetHandler is the part that
# follows the pipe. If you need to distinguish, "localhost; can
# be anything unique.
<Proxy "fcgi://localhost/" enablereuse=on max=10>
</Proxy>
```

With this configuration I was seeing unexplained 503 proxy errors from Apache with the application periodically unresponsive until PHP-FPM was restarted. After adding `request_terminate_timeout = 5m` to my `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to force-kill long-running PHP-FPM requests my application became a bit more stable and I began seeing errors like the following in my `/var/log/php-fpm/error.log` and less frequent failures that would last for a few minutes before recovering without intervention:

```
[04-Jan-2023 15:19:26] WARNING: [pool www] child 349975, script '' (request: " ") execution timed out (362.004673 sec), terminating
[04-Jan-2023 15:19:26] WARNING: [pool www] child 349975 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 1200.012433 seconds from start
```

After removing the `enablereuse=on` flag from my Apache configuration I no longer see the above timeout errors in my `/var/log/php-fpm/error.log`. The new configuration is:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
  <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
    # Pick one of the following approaches
    #
    # Use the standard TCP socket
    #SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
    # If your version of httpd is 2.4.9 or newer (or has the back-ported feature), you can use the unix domain socket
    #SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/app.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
  </If>
</FilesMatch>

# Defining a worker will improve performance
# And in this case, re-use the worker (dependent on support from the fcgi application)
# If you have enough idle workers, this would only improve the performance marginally
#
# enablereuse=on is only available in Apache >= 2.4.11
<Proxy "fcgi://localhost/" max=10>
</Proxy>
```